# automating to push changes to github for multiple repos using python

Tags: python, python-2.x, git

This Python script does following activities:

- clone repo, as provided from the list
- creating a new branch "jenkinsMigrate"
- rename Jenkinsfile to Jenkinsfile.migrate
- push code to GitHub in a new branch.

NOTE: credentials were configured already.

```
import git
import os
import subprocess

gitUrl = "https://*****"
cwd = "*****"

with open("migrateList.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        #configure gitUri for each repository
        gitUri = gitUrl + line.strip() + ".git"
        try:
            global repo
            repo = git.Repo.clone_from(gitUri, cwd + line.strip())
        except:
            print(" directory already available")
        os.chdir(cwd + line.strip())

        #checkout new branch for migration
        repo.git.checkout('-b', "jenkinsMigrate")

        subprocess.call(["git", "mv", "Jenkinsfile", "Jenkinsfile.migrate"])
        repo.git.add(update=True)
        repo.index.commit("jenkins migration")
        origin = repo.remote(name='origin')

        #push new branch to github
        subprocess.call(["git","push", "--set-upstream", "origin", "jenkinsMigrate"])
        subprocess.call(["cd", ".."])
```

Sample text file:

```
$ cat migrateList.txt 
repo1
repo2
repo3
repo4
```

This is a working code, but all I am looking for is to maintain consistency in the commands that I use. eg: For some of the git commands that I have used are from gitpython module where as others are invoked with shell commands. Apart from these any other suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1:** python - 2.7.10

gitPython module

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Which `git` pacakage are you using? Probably not [git](https://pypi.org/project/git/), but maybe [GitPython](https://pypi.org/project/GitPython/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Review

- Stick to the PEP8 style guide

  1. Functions and variables should be `snake_case`
  2. Constants like `gitUrl` should be `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE`
- There is a function for getting the current working directory

  `os.getcwd()` Depending on your use case this might be useful
- If you are using Python3.5+ you should change the [older `subprocces.call` with the newer `subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module)
- Don't catch bare `Exceptions`

  If you now what exceptions are going to be caught it is better to define them

Answer (score 2):

#### Use Python 3.x

Python 2.7 will retire in 2020 (end of support) so I'd sugest you migrate your project to a newer version.

#### Other aspects apart from what [@Ludisposed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/215660/61966) already mentioned:

- you're using `line.strip()` in several places so you might want to assign it to a new variable and use that instead.
- declare the `migrateList` as a constant at the top of the file (under your imports). That way it will be easier to be modified.
- use `f-strings` (Python > 3.6). E.g: `f"{gitUrl}{line.strip()}.git"`
- don't use `global`s. The reason they are bad is that they allow functions/variables to have hidden (as in *non-obvious* and *undeclared*) and thus hard to understand side effects. Also, this can lead to Spaghetti code.
- [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments): leave an empty space after `#` in your comments. E.g: `# configure gitUri for each repository`
- [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> Imports should be grouped in the following order:
>
> - Standard library imports.
> - Related third party imports.
> - Local application/library specific imports.
> - **You should put a blank line between each group of imports.**